# Same key - Different Value with a HashMap

Tags: java, android, arrays, hashmap

I'll start with what I want to achieve

**Intention**

The software parses XML-Data in a for-loop. The for-loop which handles the data will go until 50 (because I'm getting 50 different results). What I did at first was, that the `doInBackground`-method parses the whole XML data and saves it into TextViews and displays it. But now I wanted to add a splash-screen that gets displayed as long the data loads.

The XML-File is built up like any other normal XML-file, so when I go through a for-loop the keys are always the same, but the values differ.

**Approaches**

What I already did was to create an multidimensional array, but unfortunately you can't use Strings as an index. That's what the Map is for. This was my approach

```
stringArray[i]["source"] = sourceString;
```

Well, then I tried it with a Map. But the problem with the map was, that when the new key came again, it would just overwrite the previous key-value pair.

So I figured out I would use a HashMap with a String Collection. I handled it like this;
First I created the HashMap

```
public HashMap <String, Collection<String>> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Collection<String>>();
```

Then I put data in the HashMap for each key.

```
hashMap.put("source"        , new ArrayList<String>());
```

This is what I have done in the for-loop

```
hashMap.get("source").add(new String(((Node) sourceList.item(0)).getNodeValue()));
```

Then, when finished, the `onPostExecute`-method starts a new intent and passes the hashMap.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("hashMap", hashMap);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

And in my MainActivity I'm doing this to get the data

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>)intent.getSerializableExtra("hashMap");
rankingDate = new TextView(this);
rankingDate.setText("RankingDate: " + hashMap.get("rankingDate"));
layout.addView(rankingDate);
```

But this results in a ClassCastException : `ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String" in this line

`source.setText("source: " + hashMap.get("source"));`

I guess it's because `hashMap.get("source")` contains all values of the source data. So I tried to save all the data in a String Array. But this didn't work, but I don't know why. Eclipse tells me that `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to String[]`

Any advice? I'm dying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got a typo:

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>)intent.getSerializableExtra("hashMap");
```

should be:

```
HashMap<String, Collection<String>> hashMap = (HashMap<String, Collection<String>>)intent.getSerializableExtra("hashMap");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But now I still have the problem on how to read out. Do I understand it correctly that if I would do now Collection<String> source = hashMap.get("source") - that I now have every source of the XML file in the source-Collection? Or what would be the best way to read out the data. It would be perfect if I could save all data in an array because I need to read out by index

Comment: Personally I would replace `Collection<String>` with `List<String>`. Now, say that you need the second element with key `foo`, then just use: `String element = map.get("foo").get(1);`.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, but I have to ask you again one question if I may. When I'm doing exactly this it tells me `The method get(int) is undefined for the type Collection<String>` 

So, do I have to change my HashMap now? Or how would I go with getting the first index.

Comment: That's why I told you to change `Collection<String>` to `List<String` :)

Comment: Ah ok, I changed the wrong collection. Now it works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@Eng.Fouad answer is correct, you have an error in the casting.

You might consider using a MultiMap rather than a map of collections:

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a list of maps.
You can call list.get(index).get("source") and get the result later.

semi pseudocode:

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>

foreach(entry in document)
  map = new HashMap<String,String>();
  foreach(xml in entry)
   map.put(xml,xml.value)
  end
  list.put(index++,map)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your casting your hashmap incorrectly in your main activity.

Try this:

```
HashMap<String, Collection<String>> hashMap = (HashMap<String, Collection<String>>)intent.getSerializableExtra("hashMap");
```

Hope this helps :)